# EJB-like transactions in JAX-RS

Tags: transactions, jax-rs

I'm adding a RESTful API to an existing application (JBoss 4, EJB 2, adding RESTEasy).  The application currently has Session beans with container-managed transactions.  To start with, I'm calling remote interfaces on the Enterprise Beans.  The EJB usage is being phased out, so new functionality will be added without writing new methods on the beans.

Does JAX-RS or JBoss 4 offer any transaction support on the resource methods?  Or do I have to write my own transaction code in each of the resource methods?

JAX-RS has PreProcessInterceptors and PostProcessInterceptors, but does not appear to have an interceptor that wraps an invocation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use the session beans as your JAX-RS service?  Having container managed transactions works very well with Java EE.

For an example see:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-45.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want your exposed REST services to be 'managed' by a transaction you might want to have a look at [Transactional support for JAX RS based applications](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/TransactionalSupportForJAXRSBasedApplications)

Answer (score 0):

I need to invoke a method from inside JAX-RS bean such that takes as param entity object so program flow must be inside one transaction to not throw detached entity exception.

Finally I have @Injected (CDI) UserTransaction object to my JAX-RS Bean (Class) and wrap code inside this method as :

```
userTransaction.begin(); 
// code requiring transaction goes here 
userTransaction.commit();
```

It seems to work correctly for me returning good results.